# onRequestPermissionsResult is compiling under fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am requesting run time permission for my app from fragment. i can able to call requestPermissions.

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONE_STATE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But when i add the onRequestPermissionsResult, its not compiling and says "Method does not override method from its superclass.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
}
```

Can anyone help me out on this.

Comment: Do you use `android.app.Fragment` or support Fragments? Can you add your `build.gradle` file, too?

Comment: i have this "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'" @Christopher

Comment: I assume you use support Fragments than as well?! For your support lib, it's too old. This is the Lollipop support lib. Try to update to at least 23+ or the current one (28.+).

Comment: Great yaar. Thanks @Christopher

Answer (score 0):

[image]> inside onCreateView

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getActivity().requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 0);
    }
```

> inside fragment class

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

}
```

Comment: I added inside fragment only

Comment: Still the same error "Method does not override method from its superclass."

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in onCreateView() method to request permission

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
```

AND

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was " + grantResults[0]);
        }
    }
```

Also in your manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```